# C# Loop checkbox and add value

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, checkbox

I'm trying to add values of phones numbers based on checkbox's in the UI.
For example if a checkbox1 (which represent phone1) is checked and checkbox2 is also checked then the program will add both phones' values. 
How can I add the value (in for loop for example) so that the if statement is lesser and simplified.

Here is my code:

```
public double totalPhone()
    {
        double total = 0;
        double item1 = 2249;
        double item2 = 1769;
        double item3 = 3099;
        double item4 = 1198;
        double item5 = 1899;

        if (chkPhone1.Checked == true)
        {
            total = total + item1;
        }

        if (chkPhone2.Checked == true)
        {
            total = total + item2;
        }

        if (chkPhone3.Checked == true)
        {
            total = total + item3;
        }

        if (chkPhone4.Checked == true)
        {
            total = total + item4;
        }

        if (chkPhone5.Checked == true)
        {
            total = total + item5;
        }

        return total;
    }
```

Comment: what kind of application is this?

Comment: Do you have fixed checkbox? Their values are fixed (like 2249, 1769, etc...) ?

Comment: What have you tried on the loop front? I'd imagine you would have something like the check boxes in a collection that you iterate through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming these checkbox's are all in the same GroupBox control just loop over the controls in that specific groupbox. I tested this and it seems to work. Use the checkbox item's Tag property to store the value associated to it:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private static double Total { get; set; }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ctrl = groupBox1;
        foreach (var checkBox in ctrl.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
        {
            Total = checkBox.Checked ? (Total + Convert.ToDouble(checkBox.Tag)) : Total;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How to fix this. "The name 'Total' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Look at the variable Total in the class above

Comment: Why the Total keep doubling?

Comment: The Total variable in the code above is just summing all of he "checked" checkboxs

Comment: Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

You can store the ids of the checkboxes and its corresponding values in a Dictionary and then loop through the controls,check for its type and checked property and then add the value corresponding to the id of the checkbox from the dictionary.

Note:Code is not tested but this should get you on the way.

```
public double totalPhone()
{
    double total = 0;
    Dictionary<string,double> items = new Dictionary<string,double>();

    items.Add(chkPhone1.ID,2249); // ID,Text whatever works
    items.Add(chkPhone2.ID,1769);
    items.Add(chkPhone3.ID,3099);
    items.Add(chkPhone4.ID,1198);
    items.Add(chkPhone5.ID,1899);

    foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
    { 
        if(c is CheckBox && c.Checked)
        {
             total += (items[c.ID] != null ? items[c.ID] : 0);
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is some re-factoring required on your code, but I don't see any case to use loop for this simple case.

Still interested? You could do something like this. Please note this code assume one to one mapping between **item**  and **checkbox name**.

```
Dictionary<string, int> values = new Dictionary<string,int>();

int total = 0;
values.Add("item1", 2249);
values.Add("item2", 1769);
values.Add("item3", 3099);
values.Add("item4", 1198);
values.Add("item5", 1899);


foreach( CheckBox cb in this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()
                            .Where(c=>c.Checked))
{
    int itemprice;
    if(values.TryGetValue("item"+ Regex.Match(cb.Text, @"\d+").Value, out itemprice))
    {
         total+=itemprice;
    }
}
```

Comment: if I want to calculate the total price of the phone in certain groupbox, where should I change the code?

Comment: I get different value for different item. I don't know why.